# Split By Longest Regex Matching Substring

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone please tell me how can I find the longest substring of a given string which matches a given Regex?

Comment: Can there be overlap between the potential matches? Perhaps some example strings and regexes would help to illustrate the problem.

Comment: For example, let's say I have the Regex "[ ]+" which matches one or more spaces. If I have the string "Test<-spaces->." I want to be able to match all the spaces between "Test" and ".".

Comment: you can edit your original question to add examples to it. No need to cram it in the comment-box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, a regular expression engine will find the leftmost, longest match in a string (unless you explicitly tell it not to).

So the regex `X+` will always match `XXXXX` in `testXXXXX.`.

However, if there is more than one potential match in the string, the standard `find` methods will always find the first, not necessarily the longest match (say, in `test1XXtest2XXXXX.`). To find the longest match here, you need to use the `findall` method of your regex engine and then measure the length of all the matches.

In C#, this might look like this:

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex("[ ]+");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

(and after that, find the longest string in `resultList`.)

There is a problem, though, if potential matches can overlap. Take for example the regex

```
AB+A
```

and the string

```
ABABBA
```

If you apply the regex, you will only find `ABA` because the regex engine has consumed the second `A` after the first match, so it starts the second attempt at the `B` of `BBA` and fails, of course. This is a consequence of the "leftmost-longest" behaviour, and if you want to circumvent that, you'd have to reapply the regex "manually" to the entire string, then to the entire string minus the first character, then to the entire string minus the first two characters, etc.

Comment: to get around the overlapping problem, you could put the section that could overlap in a lookahead so it isn't consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the matches and compare the length.

Comment: That will fail if the potential matches overlap.